# Axios - get gz information from url

Tags: javascript, http, request, axios, gzip

Do you know how I could and use an xml.gz file from a http request using axios?

Currently, I'm doing the below:

```
let test = async () => {
    let response = await axios('https://url.com/info-24.xml.gz')
    let html = response.data

    console.log(html)

}
```

but I get a weird response such as below

**data**

> \u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003Ľ��n�q���W!��4D�u�ᇽw/W��Iϱ�m!:\u0018�\u0012;w�*��\u0002�pp
>   x����\u0005؞s>�~r�UŪ����������\u000f���?��/��ے�o���*������������w��������?��O���
>   c��/��������o?������������?����*�����o��������������oן��������������ϔ1�������c�����������[����_�?��Ͽ��\u001f���?

Any way to get the raw information from the file via axios get?

Thanks

Comment: A `.gz` file is compressed -- hence the garbage output. You need to uncompress it first. Perhaps take a look at zlib.js: https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/develop/README.en.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider these two things

1. Set axios `responseType` to `arraybuffer`.
2. Using zlib for decompressing.

```
const zlib = require('zlib')

let url = "https://url.com/info-24.xml.gz"

const { data } = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })

zlib.gunzip(data, function (_err, output) {
    console.log(output.toString())
  })
```